# Converting from AD&D Second Edition to AD&D

Tags: adnd-1e, adnd-2e, conversion

I have a lot of old AD&D 2nd Edition books, but I only have the core books for AD&D 1st Edition, plus the *Deities and Demigods* book. **I am looking for a way to convert second edition to first**, because there is *way* more content merging the two. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is one you may want to look at if you haven't yet. @aramis gives a good answer. [Is it possible to mix different versions of AD&D?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9452/is-it-possible-to-mix-different-versions-of-add)

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer: have fun.

The class progression, stat blocks, and wordings are slightly different, but in practice 1E and 2E are pretty much interchangeable. It's comparable to the difference between 3.0 and 3.5. In particular, using an adventure from either one under the rules of the other is almost seamless. Rules-lawyering players might complain about a few details, but that's a separate issue.